# X509Certificate2 to X509Certificate on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to make the following code work on WP8, the problem is that there is no X509Certificate2 class on WP8, I have tried using bouncy castle apis but I haven't really managed to figure it out.

Is there a way to make this code work on WP8?

```
    private string InitAuth(X509Certificate2 certificate, string systemId, string username, string password)
    { 
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        var cipherB64 = string.Empty;
        using (var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key)
            cipherB64 = systemId + "^" + username + "^" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(plainBytes, true));

        return cipherB64;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just work around the availability of `X509Certificate2`?

```
private string InitAuth(X509Certificate certificate, string systemId, string username, string password)
    { 
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        var cipherB64 = string.Empty;

        //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        //Create a new instance of RSAParameters.
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();

        //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = certificate.getPublicKey();
        RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = new byte[3] {1,0,1};;

        //Import key parameters into RSA.
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        using (RSA)
            cipherB64 = systemId + "^" + username + "^" + Convert.ToBase64String(RSA.Encrypt(plainBytes, true));

        return cipherB64;
    }
```

DISCLOSURE: I did not try the code above because I don't have a C# runtime environment at my disposal currently.

Comment: @MaryJ. have you had a look at it?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't had the time to do that yet

Comment: please  answer  this  question...                                                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780620/x509certificate2-class-for-windows-phone-8            @likeitlikeit